# What is the most available high-temp superconductor for samples and study?

Tags: transformer, inductor, conductive, superconductors

I could only find one named [Amperium](http://www.amsc.com/products/amperiumwire/index.html) on the web, but not on the eBay or any little shops. It is very interesting material with conductivity 40 times better than copper. Is it possible to buy anywhere a little sample of material like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eBay is not the right resource for materials like this, and neither are little shops. This is a highly specialized material, which is rare and probably very expensive. If it weren't you would find it in every motor or generator. I would contact the manufacturer for information on distributors (if any) and availability.

*Note: If it conducts only 40 times better than copper (website says 100) technically it's not a superconductor. Those have zero resistance.*

Comment: There's still a limit how much current a superconductor can tolerate before superconduction breaks down. They are probably referring to this when they say that it conducts n times better than copper.